# Possible CRON Job Help

Tags: mysql, cron

I have never used CRON or anything like that, rails etc.. before, but I think that I will need to run one. My idea is to create another DB (MySQL) to take stats of another MySQL database everyday. I would also like this to happen for every week and then every month.

Please could you tell me how I could do this?

Is CRON the right thing to use, and am I spelling it right?!

Comment: cron is a scheduler that lets you run commands. You'll need to write the program that collects the stats and then schedule it to be executed using cron.

Comment: What language would the command/program need to be written in?

Comment: Depends on your operating system, your preferences... if you can extract this stats from the command line, and you're using linux, you could write a Bash script and set cron to run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron is a task scheduler for *nix systems. There are plenty of resources out there how to use it. Briefly:

- You need a script that uses some kind of language that can connect to your database (perl/php) are good options
- Assuming cron is installed in your system, in a terminal type crontab -e and the format you can find here at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)